# Dockerfile: how to forward ports?

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, server

I have a nodejs application. It runs in a container. I need to forward ports to the host machine. I ask for your help.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN yarn
EXPOSE 4200
```

try:

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:4200:4200  -t -d --name vub vub
# or
docker run -p 4200:4200  -t -d --name vub vub
```

My application is running on port 4200. The operation of the application can be checked through

```
curl http://localhost:4200/
```

In the container, the application works correctly.

Why can't I see the application on the host machine(http://localhost:4200/)? How to fix it?

Comment: How is your application setting up the listening port?  What is your host OS, and what "kind" of Docker is it (in particular, are you using Docker Toolbox or another VM-based setup)?

Comment: macos. I only do what I described

Comment: You need to find out docker container IP address

Comment: @Anatoly The container-private IP address is inaccessible from MacOS, and you shouldn't need to look it up on any platform.

Comment: Is it an Express application; can you show your `app.listen()` call or whatever else does similar setup?

Comment: Did you check on your terminal with `docker ps` if your local port 4200 was redirect to the port 4200 of your running container? If true, under PORTS column of `docker ps` output you can see like `0.0.0.0:4200->4200/tcp`

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that there's a server running, with express or something responsible for the same functionalities. If all you're doing is printing a "hello world" on the terminal the container will exit.

Your question could be improved with the full source code.